# Python Terminal Calls Fail to Interact with Files

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, permissions

I am writing a program that handles some data on a server. Throughout the program, many files are made and sent as input into other programs. To do this, I usually make the command string, then run it like so:

```
cmd = "prog input_file1 input_file2 > outputfile"
os.system(cmd)
```

When I run the command, however, the programs being called report that they cannot open the files. If I run the python code on my local computer, it is fine. When I loaded it onto the server, it started to fail. I think this is related to issues with permissions, but am not sure how I can fix this. Many of the files, particularly the output files, are being created at run time. The input files have full permissions for all users. Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Check the permissions on the directory containing the generated files: the process running the script must have write permissions on the directory in order to create files within it.

Comment: The directory has full permissions for all users.

Comment: Does your local PC run Windows and the server Linux? The local directory is not an element of the search path in Linux, so `prog something` usually raises an error message like `prog: command not found`. You have to name the directory in which "prog" is located. `./prog something` should work.

Comment: The server is Linux and my local computer is a Mac. The programs are running, they are just having issues with accessing the files. One of them is a program called pullseq, and it is giving me output, just saying that it can't open the files.

Answer (score 0):

The python code you list is simple and correct, so the problem is likely not in the two lines of your example. Here are some related areas for you to check out.

**Permissions**
The user running the python script must have the appropriate permission (read, write, execute). I see from comments that you've already checked this.

**What command are you running**
If the command is literally typed into your source code like in the example, then you know what command is being run, but if you are generating any part of it (eg. the list of operands, the name of the output file, other parameters, etc), make sure there are no bugs in the portions of your code that generate the command. For example before the call to `os.system(cmd)` consider including a line like `print("About to execute: " + cmd)` so you can see exactly what will be run.

**Directly invoke the command**
If all the above looks good, try to execute the command directly at a terminal on your server. What output do you get then. It's possible that the problem is with the underlying command itself rather than your python code.